# How to pass a html tag inside as variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am passing an array called floors into a function which creates a html node.

```
var floors = ["Ground", "First", "Second", "Third", "Duplex", "Duplex+1", "Duplex+2"];
document.createTextNode(" " + floors[flooring]);
```

Is there anyway to add a html tag to each of these variables.  I have tried the below code, but it does not seem to work.

```
var floors = ["<label>Ground</label>", "<label>First</label>"], AND

document.createTextNode('<label> + floors[flooring] +'</label>');
```

Is there anyway possible to add html tags to these variable in javascript. Please help.

Comment: What is `flooring`?

Comment: TextNodes contain text, not HTML. But you can do `var el = document.createElement('label'); el.innerHTML = floors[flooring];` (assuming `flooring` is a numeric index)

Comment: [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) might be of use

Comment: flooring is numeric index

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `createTextNode()`, use [**`createElement()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and set its `innerHTML`:

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.innerHTML = floors[flooring];
```

Comment: Thank you, this was simple and worked best.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `innerHTML`.

```js
const elements = [
  "<h1>First</h1>",
  "<h1>Second</h1>",
  "<h1>Third</h1>",
  "<h1>Fourth</h1>"
]

for (let el of elements) {
  document.body.innerHTML += el
}
```